ERROR TypeError: tabBarBackground is not a function (it is Object)
ERROR  TypeError: tabBarBackground is not a function (it is Object)
node: v18.20.3
yarn: 1.22.21
@react-navigation/native: ^6.0.13
react: 18.2.0
react-native: 0.72.3
trying add tabBarBackground in screenOptions of the Tab.Navigator i receive the ERROR  TypeError: tabBarBackground is not a function (it is Object)
error
enter image description here

try to send it as callback function like this
tabbarbackground:()=><ImageBackground  source=require(‘./../../assets/images/my-image.png') {…your props}/>

